# Horizontal bar at top center of screen display what I last typed

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, screen

A black bar with random text appeared in the center of my screen. Whenever I type something, the text in the black bar changes. I have MacBook Pro Late 2011 running on macOS 10.13.6. I have no idea what could be causing this and how to fix this.Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: Screenshot of area where text appears]

[image: Full screen]

Comment: can we have larger screen shot

Comment: Does this occur after a Restart? What apps are running when this happens?

Comment: This does not occur after restart. Firefox and mail were both running when this happened.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this only happens for me when the iOS simulator is open.